# Errror in confusionMatrix in R

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, r, classification, predictive-modeling

While i am using the `confusionMatrix` in R, I am getting the following error:

Error in `binom.test(sum(diag(x)), sum(x))` : 
  'n' must be a positive integer >= 'x'

The code i use as follows:

`rf.pred <- predict(rf, testing, type = "class")

confusionMatrix(rf.pred, testing$target)`

Comment: does this not belong on stack overflow?

Comment: @aeroNotAuto - I apologize if i had posted in wrong place. I thought confusionMatrix is something related to data science and hence posted here.

Comment: @Arun, confusionMatrix is related to data science but your problem is regarding troubleshooting code.  As such it is best to be moved to stackOverflow.

Comment: This is a tough call. It could well be posted on SO. This site is also about data science in practice, including tools. While SO is a somewhat better site I'd stop short of calling it off-topic here. The answer here is related to what the operation means and why the constraint in question here is needed and why it may have been violated

Comment: Please have a look at rf.pred, testing$target. I got similar error when i ended up in passing a NULL value target class(due to wrong slicing) to confusion matrix. Note: I'm not able to post a comment.